# How to access the class variable of abstract class in non abstract class?

Tags: java, abstract-class

I have abstract class which is having a variable at class levele.Now i want to use this variable in other class.How can i achieve it?

**Following is my code**

```
public abstract class MyClass
{    
String name="John";
}
```

Comment: 1. Extend that class or 2. Use reflection. :D

Comment: post an example please

Comment: @TarunSharma , first you need to post your code. "Help others to help yourself".

Comment: I have posted the code already. just want to use value of name variable in other class

Comment: The way to use the field is to just use it.  It doesn't matter whether the class is abstract or not.  If you can't use the field, then the problem is the visibility of the field, not the abstractness of the class.  However, it is best not to use fields directly anyway--best practice is to make it private and provide a getter function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your variable `public static` and use with class name like -

```
Myclass.name
```

or else

```
public abstract class MyClass
{    
String name="John";

 String getName()
   {
      return name;
  }

}

class NewClass extends Myclass{
   //inside method 
   new NewClass().getName();
}
```

Comment: i don't want to use static

Comment: If it is a package-private member, you can simply refer to it as `name` in `NewClass`.

Answer (score 0):

Try extending the class like:

```
public class NewClass extends MyClass {
    public NewClass() {
       System.out.println(super.name);
    }
}
```

Expose getter and setter so that any instance can access that variable like:

```
MyNewClass clazz = new MyNewClass();
MyClass clazz = ....//child class?
clazz.getName();
```

Since you have defined you instance variable with default access specifier, any class instance can access it using `MyClassChildInstance.name;`

Note aside: The variable that you defined is instance specific and not class specific. If you want to make it class specific then you need to declare that variable as static.